# Shell counts the number of file lines and delete the excess

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run a cron job, when the file exceeds the specified number of lines, the job will delete the extra lines in the file.

For example, when the file has 50 lines, I want to delete the content after 30 lines.

The goal is to keep the first 30 lines of the file.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a file or piping some text to `head -n30` will keep the first 30 lines.

Examples:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | head -n2
foo
bar
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz > test.txt
$ head -n2 test.txt
foo
bar
```